# Кнопка включения-выключения в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

разрабатываю утилиту с помощью графический библиотеки Tkinter и появилась проблема - хочу сделать кнопку включения-выключения музыки но не могу ее реализовать, помогите пожалуйста как можно реализовать код кнопки для включения-выключения музыки. Буду очень благодарен если поможете

Comment: Делаешь кнопку. Вешаешь на неё функцию вкл-выкл. Профит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужен какой-то флаг включена ли музыка, например `is_music_plays`.

И при нажатии на кнопку надо проверять этот флаг, то-есть код функции, зарегистрированной на нажатие кнопки, примерно такой:

```py
if is_music_plays:
    # Выключить музыку
    is_music_plays = False
else:
    # Включить музыку
    is_music_plays = True
```